# How to change the android sdk that cocos uses?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I use this command to compile:

```
cocos run -s ./MyFolder -p android
```

Normally this uses SDK android-10, but as I was debugging some errors I tried:

```
cocos run -s ./MyFolder -p android --ap android-22
```

Now whenever I run cocos run -s ./MyFolder -p android it builds with android-22. Even if I specify:

```
cocos run -s ./MyFolder -p android --ap android-10
```

It still runs with 22. How do I get it to use 10 again ?
I did not change the default values in Application.mk . (So it still specifies 9, even though 10 is the lowest sdk installed on my system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following (some of the steps may be unnecessary, but I haven't verified yet).

1. Set the targetSDK explicitly (ApplicationManifest.xml)
2. Set the application platform
3. Update project.properties.